# How to get rate of 60 hit/s in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

how to get the target volumetry in jmeter ie a rate of 60 calls per second with a target of 2 seconds as response time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use throughput shaping timer to fire request at the rate of 60 requests per second.

For more info follow the link below

[Throughput shaping timer](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/07/throughput-shaping-timer/)